# Blender 2.6 JSON exporter, texture wrong only one side of cube

Tags: python, json, opengl, webgl, blender

I'm making a simple exporter for Blender 2.6x for a custom JSON format (mainly for use with WebGL), because the existing ones I could find online don't work with Blender 2.6.

I've almost got it working, but one bug remains that I can't figure out. On a simple cube, the texture on one of its sides is in the wrong orientation. The rest of the cube is textured properly.

You can see a picture of the problem here (the left face on the left side is in the wrong orientation, as compared to the correct cube on the right side):

[image: the bug]

Are there some common misconceptions or errors that could cause this behaviour to happen?

This is the function that exports from Blender 2.65 to my custom JSON format (the bug must be in here, but I can't find it):

```
def get_json(objects, scene):
    """ Currently only supports one scene. 
        Exports with -Z forward, Y up. """

    object_number = -1
    scene_data = []

    # for every object in the scene
    for object in bpy.context.scene.objects:

        # if the object is a mesh       
        if object.type == 'MESH':

            object_number += 1

            # convert all the mesh's faces to triangles
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            object.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object

            # triangulate using new Blender 2.65 Triangulate modifier
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')
            object.modifiers["Triangulate"].use_beauty = False
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as="DATA", modifier="Triangulate")

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

            object.select = False

            # add data to scene_data structure
            scene_data.append({
                "name"          : object.name,
                "vertices"      : [],
                "indices"       : [],
                "normals"       : [],
                "tex_coords"    : []
            })

            vertex_number = -1

            # for each face in the object
            for face in object.data.polygons:
                vertices_in_face = face.vertices[:]

                # for each vertex in the face
                for vertex in vertices_in_face:

                    vertex_number += 1

                    # store vertices in scene_data structure
                    scene_data[object_number]["vertices"].append( object.data.vertices[vertex].co.x + object.location.x )
                    scene_data[object_number]["vertices"].append( object.data.vertices[vertex].co.z + object.location.z )
                    scene_data[object_number]["vertices"].append( -(object.data.vertices[vertex].co.y + object.location.y) )

                    # store normals in scene_data structure
                    scene_data[object_number]["normals"].append( object.data.vertices[vertex].normal.x )
                    scene_data[object_number]["normals"].append( object.data.vertices[vertex].normal.z )
                    scene_data[object_number]["normals"].append( -(object.data.vertices[vertex].normal.y) )

                    # store indices in scene_data structure
                    scene_data[object_number]["indices"].append(vertex_number)

            # texture coordinates
            #   bug: for a simple cube, one face's texture is warped
            mesh = object.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, 'PREVIEW')
            if len(mesh.tessface_uv_textures) > 0:
                for data in mesh.tessface_uv_textures.active.data:
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv1.x )
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv1.y )
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv2.x )
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv2.y )
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv3.x )
                    scene_data[object_number]["tex_coords"].append( data.uv3.y )

    return json.dumps(scene_data, indent=4)
```

And in case this would help figure it out, here's the exported JSON data that results from running my export script (the same data used to render the cube on the left in the image above):

```
[
    {
        "vertices": [
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            -0.9679820388555527, 
            0.669445663690567, 
            0.9796346426010132, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            -1.330554336309433, 
            -1.0203653573989868, 
            1.0320179611444473, 
            0.669445663690567
        ], 
        "normals": [
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            -0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035, 
            0.5773491859436035
        ], 
        "indices": [
            0, 
            1, 
            2, 
            3, 
            4, 
            5, 
            6, 
            7, 
            8, 
            9, 
            10, 
            11, 
            12, 
            13, 
            14, 
            15, 
            16, 
            17, 
            18, 
            19, 
            20, 
            21, 
            22, 
            23, 
            24, 
            25, 
            26, 
            27, 
            28, 
            29, 
            30, 
            31, 
            32, 
            33, 
            34, 
            35
        ], 
        "name": "Cube", 
        "tex_coords": [
            0.008884529583156109, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.3244488537311554, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.657782256603241, 
            0.008884510956704617, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.007913422770798206, 
            0.008884549140930176, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.3244488537311554, 
            0.9920865893363953, 
            0.32444891333580017, 
            0.675551176071167, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.9911155700683594, 
            0.00791349820792675, 
            0.3412467837333679, 
            0.008884538896381855, 
            0.6577821969985962, 
            0.007913422770798206, 
            0.34221789240837097, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.6587532758712769, 
            0.6577821969985962, 
            0.3422178626060486, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.6577821373939514, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.6745801568031311, 
            0.34221789240837097, 
            0.9911155700683594, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.6755512356758118, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.007913460955023766, 
            0.34221789240837097, 
            0.3244488537311554, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.008884529583156109, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.007913422770798206, 
            0.008884549140930176, 
            0.324448823928833, 
            0.007913422770798206, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.3244488537311554, 
            0.675551176071167, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.6745801568031311, 
            0.008884529583156109, 
            0.9911155700683594, 
            0.00791349820792675, 
            0.6577821969985962, 
            0.007913422770798206, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.3244488835334778, 
            0.34221789240837097, 
            0.32541996240615845, 
            0.3422178626060486, 
            0.6587533354759216, 
            0.3412467837333679, 
            0.34221789240837097, 
            0.6577821373939514, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.9911155700683594, 
            0.3412468135356903, 
            0.99208664894104, 
            0.6577821969985962, 
            0.6755512356758118, 
            0.6587533354759216
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm not currently looking for ways to make a better more feature filled, or more efficient exporter, rather I would just like to finally squash this bug so I can get on to more interesting things, like making a WebGL game, and learning about collision detection and such. Any help or advise in regards to this problem I'm having would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

In case it might be my rendering code, and not the exporter that's the problem,
here is the part of my WebGL code related to initializing the buffers and drawing the scene (a modified version of some code found at http://learningwebgl.com):

```
var gl;

var current_shader_program;
var per_vertex_shader_program;
var per_fragment_shader_program;

var modelview_matrix = mat4.create();
var modelview_matrix_stack = [];
var projection_matrix = mat4.create();

var teapot_vertex_position_buffer = new Array();
var teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer = new Array();
var teapot_vertex_normal_buffer = new Array();
var teapot_vertex_index_buffer = new Array();

var earth_texture;
var galvanized_texture;

var teapot_angle = 180;

var last_time = 0;

function createProgram(vertex_shader_filename, fragment_shader_filename) {
    var vertex_shader_text = readFromUrl(vertex_shader_filename);
    var fragment_shader_text = readFromUrl(fragment_shader_filename);

    var vertex_shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragment_shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertex_shader, vertex_shader_text);
    gl.shaderSource(fragment_shader, fragment_shader_text);

    gl.compileShader(vertex_shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertex_shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader));
    }

    gl.compileShader(fragment_shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragment_shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader));
    }

    var shader_program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader);
    gl.attachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader);
    gl.linkProgram(shader_program);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shader_program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Error: Unable to link shaders!");
    }

    shader_program.vertex_position_attribute = 
        gl.getAttribLocation(shader_program, "a_vertex_position");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.vertex_position_attribute);

    shader_program.vertex_normal_attribute =
        gl.getAttribLocation(shader_program, "a_vertex_normal");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.vertex_normal_attribute);

    shader_program.tex_coord_attribute = 
        gl.getAttribLocation(shader_program, "a_tex_coord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.tex_coord_attribute);

    shader_program.projection_matrix_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_projection_matrix");
    shader_program.modelview_matrix_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_modelview_matrix");
    shader_program.normal_matrix_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_normal_matrix");
    shader_program.sampler_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_sampler");
    shader_program.material_shininess_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_material_shininess");
    shader_program.show_specular_highlights_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_show_specular_highlights");
    shader_program.use_textures_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_use_textures");
    shader_program.use_lighting_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_use_lighting");
    shader_program.ambient_color_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_ambient_color");
    shader_program.point_lighting_location_uniform = 
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_point_lighting_location");
    shader_program.point_lighting_specular_color_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_point_lighting_specular_color");
    shader_program.point_lighting_diffuse_color_uniform =
        gl.getUniformLocation(shader_program, "u_point_lighting_diffuse_color");

    return shader_program;
}

function initShaders() {
    per_fragment_shader_program = createProgram("per_fragment_lighting.vs", "per_fragment_lighting.fs");

}

function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTextures() {
    earth_texture = gl.createTexture();
    earth_texture.image = new Image();
    earth_texture.image.onload = function() {
        handleLoadedTexture(earth_texture);
    }
    earth_texture.image.src = "earth.jpg";

    galvanized_texture = gl.createTexture();
    galvanized_texture.image = new Image();
    galvanized_texture.image.onload = function() {
        handleLoadedTexture(galvanized_texture);
    };
    galvanized_texture.image.src = "galvanized.jpg";
}

function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(current_shader_program.projection_matrix_uniform, false, 
        projection_matrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(current_shader_program.modelview_matrix_uniform, false, 
        modelview_matrix);

    var normal_matrix = mat3.create();
    mat4.toInverseMat3(modelview_matrix, normal_matrix);
    mat3.transpose(normal_matrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(current_shader_program.normal_matrix_uniform, false, 
        normal_matrix);
}

function handleLoadedTeapot(teapot_data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < teapot_data.length; i++)
    {
        teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(teapot_data[i].normals), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i].item_size = 3;
        teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i].num_items = 
            teapot_data[i].normals.length / teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i].item_size;

        teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(teapot_data[i].tex_coords), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i].item_size = 2;
        teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i].num_items = 
            teapot_data[i].tex_coords.length / teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i].item_size;

        teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(teapot_data[i].vertices), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i].item_size = 3;
        teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i].num_items = 
            teapot_data[i].vertices.length / teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i].item_size;

        teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(teapot_data[i].indices), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW)
        teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i].item_size = 1;
        teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i].num_items = 
            teapot_data[i].indices.length / teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i].item_size;
    }

    document.getElementById("loading_text").textContent = "";
}

function loadTeapot() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "untitled.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            handleLoadedTeapot(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
        }
    };
    request.send();
}

function drawScene() {

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (teapot_vertex_position_buffer[0] == null    || 
        teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[0] == null      || 
        teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[0] == null   || 
        teapot_vertex_index_buffer[0] == null) {
        return;
    }

    current_shader_program = per_fragment_shader_program;
    gl.useProgram(current_shader_program);

    var specular_highlights = document.getElementById("specular").checked;
    gl.uniform1i(current_shader_program.show_specular_highlights_uniform, specular_highlights);

    var lighting = document.getElementById("lighting").checked;
    gl.uniform1i(current_shader_program.use_lighting_uniform, lighting);

    if (lighting) {
        gl.uniform3f(current_shader_program.ambient_color_uniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambient_r").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambient_g").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambient_b").value));

        gl.uniform3f(current_shader_program.point_lighting_location_uniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("light_pos_x").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("light_pos_y").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("light_pos_z").value));

        gl.uniform3f(current_shader_program.point_lighting_specular_color_uniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("specular_r").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("specular_g").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("specular_b").value));

        gl.uniform3f(current_shader_program.point_lighting_diffuse_color_uniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("diffuse_r").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("diffuse_g").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("diffuse_b").value));
    }

    var texture = document.getElementById("texture").value;
    gl.uniform1i(current_shader_program.use_textures_uniform, texture != "none");

    mat4.identity(modelview_matrix);
    mat4.translate(modelview_matrix, [0, 0, -10]);

    mat4.rotate(modelview_matrix, degToRad(23.4), [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(modelview_matrix, degToRad(teapot_angle), [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    if (texture == "earth") {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, earth_texture);
    }
    else if (texture == "galvanized") {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, galvanized_texture);
    }
    gl.uniform1i(current_shader_program.sampler_uniform, 0);

    gl.uniform1f(current_shader_program.material_shininess_uniform, 
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("shininess").value));

    for (var i = 0; i < teapot_vertex_position_buffer.length; i++)
    {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(current_shader_program.vertex_position_attribute,
            teapot_vertex_position_buffer[i].item_size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(current_shader_program.tex_coord_attribute,
            teapot_vertex_tex_coord_buffer[i].item_size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(current_shader_program.vertex_normal_attribute,
            teapot_vertex_normal_buffer[i].item_size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i]);

        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, teapot_vertex_index_buffer[i].num_items, 
            gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
}
```

I know it's a hell of a lot to look through, which is why I didn't post it before, but there has been a suggestion that the rendering code might be at fault. Note that the "teapot" mentioned in the code is really the exported model (the cube I'm trying to render).

Comment: Not my field so I can't help, but a +1 for a good question if that's any consolation

Comment: I don´t think you can simply swap the y and z positions expecting the UVs to still be 100% correct.

Comment: That does make some sense, but if that's the case, how would I go about achieving a -Z forward, Y up orientation with valid texture coordinates?

Comment: I would first export the scene with x,y,z positions and see if that fixes the problem. Then you either have make your exporter properly transform the scene data, or you could define a default matrix for your scene doing this transformation.

Comment: I tried exporting without swapping anything around, and unfortunately the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Is your  WebGL rendering correct?  I'm not doubting that it is, but I wouldn't want to look in the wrong place.

Comment: @Kaiged I added the part of my webgl code related to rendering (and a bit extra to put it in context). I don't see anything wrong with it, but I'm no expert in GL (though I'd like to get there some day).

Comment: Hi, I think your indices are being exported incorrectly. From your script you are just using the vertex_number increment but this does not necessarily order your vertices correctly. I am working on a similar script if I get it working I will post it as solution

Answer (score 1):

As ejrowley commented, the indexing of your vertices and texture coordinates are not aligned.

Also using `to_mesh` *after* exporting the vertices can lead to a lot of craziness.

You can figure out the correct indexing using your mesh's `tessfaces`.